# ASP.NET Web service generate DUPLICATE print jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, soap, printing

I am develop a ASP.NET (SOAP) web service for print KOT/BOT print outs . I am using "PrintDocument" class for handle print jobs and the printer is Epson TM U220 network printer. The problem is when calling the print web method sometimes its generate DUPLICATE print outs. But according to my system logs, from the web method call print function only onetime, but from the Printer (**Epson TM U220**) generate same print out twice. Also this not happening every time. We are also unable figure out in which point this issue is occur. 
Also this problem not occurring in our office testing environment. This happening our one client site only. Customer complain time to time, system generate DUPLICATE KOT/BOT printouts. And also their not using dedicated server PC for the IIS server and SQL server database. Their using standard shared PC for system. So is this a problem of the web service, IIS server or the Hardware (System PC or LAN Network communication between PC and the Printer)?

Comment: does the web service have anything to do with calling actual print jobs on the Printer / Device..? if not you can eliminate the web service as the problem.. also can others actually hav access to print the same jobs meaning can person-A and person-B ever queue the same print job..?

Answer (score 0):

By the way is this AutoCutter or not?  Epson has a "Serial emulation driver" that makes a USB printer act like it's on a real serial port. Then you can use direct-to-port in Campground Master, set up as a serial printer and test it whether its keep hapenning duplicate printing. but you might need to use service to talk to port in the destination computer (local port printing) we did sometime when we had simillar issue.May be this help to you

Comment: Thank You very much. I will try your method.